# Join Tables with multiple levels of aggregation

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, aggregation

I have a huge problem cause I'm trying to do this:

[Edit]: Based upon the commentary of @gordon-linoff I remodeled my question with some concrete example

I have to join two tables Sales and Quota.
Table Sales:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Country |   Year  | Store   | Manager |  Vendor | Customer|
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    MX   |   2018  |Cid. Mex.| Orlando |  Luiz   |   001   |
|    MX   |   2018  |Cid. Mex.| Orlando |  Fabio  |   002   |
|    MX   |   2018  |Cid. Mex.| Orlando |  Luiz   |   003   |
|    MX   |   2018  |Cid. Mex.| Orlando |  Juan   |   004   |
|    MX   |   2018  |Cid. Mex.| Orlando |  Juan   |   005   |
|    MX   |   2018  |Cid. Mex.| Javier  |Hernandez|   007   |
...
```

And Quota:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+------------+
| Country |   Year  | Store   | Manager |  Vendor | Customer|  Target    |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+------------+
|    MX   |  2018   |Cid. Mex.| Orlando |  Luiz   |  001    |     1,01   |
|    MX   |  2018   |Cid. Mex.| Orlando |  Fabio  |         |     2,00   |
|    MX   |  2018   |Cid. Mex.| Orlando |  Luiz   |         |     3,05   |
|    MX   |  2018   |Cid. Mex.| Orlando |  Juan   |  004    |     2,71   |
|    MX   |  2018   |Cid. Mex.| Orlando |         |         |    14,25   |
|    MX   |  2018   |Cid. Mex.|         |         |         |     16,1   |
...
```

And I want to something like this in the end:
(Sales JOIN Quota):

```
|                     SALES FIELDS                          ||   QUOTA    |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------++------------+
| Country |   Year  | Store   | Manager |  Vendor | Customer||  Target    |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------++------------+
|    MX   |   2018  |Cid. Mex | Orlando |  Luiz   |  001    ||     1,01   | *1
|    MX   |   2018  |Cid. Mex | Orlando |  Fabio  |  002    ||     2,00   | *2
|    MX   |   2018  |Cid. Mex | Orlando |  Luiz   |  003    ||     3,05   | *3
|    MX   |   2018  |Cid. Mex | Orlando |  Juan   |  004    ||     2,71   | *4
|    MX   |   2018  |Cid. Mex | Orlando |  Juan   |  004    ||    14,25   | *5
|    MX   |   2018  |Cid. Mex | Javier  |Hernandez|  004    ||     16,1   | *6
...
```

Explain the result I'm looking for:

1. As the "key" country+year+store+manager+vendor+customer matches in both tables I brought the 'target' from table 'Quota'.
2. In this example was defined a sales quota for the Vendor Fabio, regardless the customers, so in every row that Fabio appears (in the same country, same year, same store and same manager, as a "key"), must appear his quota.
3. In this example, we see that is defined a quota for Luiz (as was defined a quota for Fabio), but this time Luiz has a quota for customer 001, as we saw in the example (1), but client 001 is a big client, and have a particular quota, for all other customers Luiz have a more opened quota.
4. The same as example (1)
5. In this example we see that a "default" value for quota to all Vendors. As Luiz, Fabio, Juan e Hernandez have their own quota, these values are not changed.
6. Here we have the same concept of "default" value for quota, but in this time in a level above the previous example.

I think it is now clearer, but if something is still hindering understanding, please let me know.

Please help me people.

Thanks in advance for this.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Scrolling through a bunch of columns trying to figure out what you mean is a big deterrent to understanding what you want to do.

Comment: Looking at the sales table we see that the three rows you show last are all the same. They have a perfect match with the fourth quota row. So why do we see this/these sales row(s) with three different targets in the result? I don't understand what rule applies here.

Comment: Please read & act on [ask] (especially about homework), hits googling 'stackexhange homework' & the downvote arrow mouseover text. Please show some work with justification, explain about the first place you get stuck & ask a specific question about it. Now you are just asking us to do your work for you. PS Please read & act on [mcve]. Show that your program calculates what you expect it to as it goes through (sub)expressions by saying what that is & showing that it actually does it via incremental output. When you add more that stumps you, ask about the difference.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, I fixed. So the 4th example is the same as the first one, but the 5th example only 4 fields matchs, but as we don't have any "longer" key this is the rule apllied. The same applies to the 6th example, but in one degree higher. I've tried to use some nested queries and CTE queries, but I'm stucked in this problem for a couple days from now.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097)

Comment: I understand the joins for the first five sales rows now. You always use the best matching quota. But for Hernandez you don't join the best match (14,25), but a worse match (16,1). Why?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, sorry again, I confused the line when I elaborate the example. In the 6th example again the best match is made (the "key" used to join is "MX2018Cid.Mex."). I don't know if was clear one thing: As was very pointed by you the best match is always done, and once one register of table Sales have a match in the Quota table, then this register is not matched with other Quota register, so I guess the relationship between the two tables is: Sales(n) -> Quota(1), as multiple registers in Sales can match with just one register in Quota.

Comment: What happened to customer 005 and 007?  and why do customers 002, and 003 show up when the last two records in expected results are 004?

Comment: Obrigado e Boa Sorte!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example may not work perfectly, but I think you can accomplish what you want by using multiple left joins and a `coalesce`.  Try this and let me know how close it is:

```
select
  s.*,
  coalesce (q1.target, q2.target, q3.target, q4.target) as target
from
  sales s
  left join quota q1 on
    s.country = q1.country and
    s.year = q1.year and
    s.manager = q1.manager and
    s.vendor = q1.vendor and
    s.customer = q1.customer
  left join quota q2 on
    s.country = q2.country and
    s.year = q2.year and
    s.manager = q2.manager and
    s.vendor = q2.vendor and
    q2.customer is null
  left join quota q3 on
    s.country = q3.country and
    s.year = q3.year and
    s.manager = q3.manager and
    q3.vendor is null and
    q3.customer is null
  left join quota q4 on
    s.country = q4.country and
    s.year = q4.year and
    q4.manager is null and
    q4.vendor is null and
    q4.customer is null
```

Essentially you are doing multiple joins to the same table and attempting to pick the join that has the most matches first, then cascading down until you find a match.

Comment: As the join criteria is lessened, wouldn't the cardinality of the joins increase thus you'll get more rows and therefore need to also handle it? (I was thinking something similar using a case expression but ran into this as well).

Comment: @xQbert -- I *thought* handled that with the `qx.customer is null` in the join, but I haven't tested this with real data, so I can't say with 100% confidence that it doesn't do what you describe.  I was too lazy to actually load the sample data the OP provided, more trying to lay the framework for a possible solution

Comment: ah I missed that and you did.  The only thing unexpected is the customer 005 and 007 doesn't match expected results; but those could be wrong thus my original comment to the question.  still; looks good to me :P

Comment: https://rextester.com/PXM9452  incase someone want's to play around with this answer: No need to reinvent the table structure & data.

Comment: Hey guys, first of all, thanks for the answer and all help trying to understand my problem, I'll test and let you know.

Comment: Hey @Hambone that is exactly I was looking for. Thank you, and thank you to you guys that help me to understand ym problem better. :)

Comment: @xQbert: Thank you for the rextester link. I've used it to validate my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your wrong examples made the task look more complicated than it actually is :-) What you want boils down to: from the quota matches we find for a sales record take the most precise match.

In PostgreSQL you can do this with `DISTINCT ON`. In other DBMS you'd use `ROW_NUMBER` with `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES` or the like.

```
select distinct on (s.customer, s.country, s.vendor, s.manager, s.store, s.year)
  s.*, q.target
from sales s
join quota q on  (q.country = s.country or q.country is null)
             and (q.year = s.year or q.year is null)
             and (q.store = s.store or q.store is null)
             and (q.manager = s.manager or q.manager is null)
             and (q.vendor = s.vendor or q.vendor is null)
             and (q.customer = s.customer or q.customer is null)
order by
  s.customer, s.country, s.vendor, s.manager, s.store, s.year,
  num_nonnulls(q.country, q.year, q.store, q.manager, q.vendor, q.customer) desc;
```